# IBAction methods in class extensions?

Tags: objective-c, ibaction, class-extensions

Is it good programming practice to define all (`IBAction`) methods associated with a `NSViewController`'s .xib within a class extension?

Answer (score 1):

Everything that's in the class extension is private to your class.

So the real question here is your `IBAction` here is private to your view controller or not. If that's something used internally, like the press of a button to activate a function inside your view controller, then yes, put it in your class extension.

Comment: Doesn't putting an IBAction in a class extension hide it from IB connections, because it's in the implementation file instead of the header file?

Comment: Very cool! But not until the latest and greatest is out of beta :)

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason to declare the `IBAction` in the class extension, if the intent is merely to make the `IBAction` method private. Just add the implementation of the action method in the controller `@implementation`.